# posterior predictive of a normal distribution with normal prior over mean and Gamma prior over precision

Tags: normal-distribution, prior, gamma-distribution, t-distribution, conjugate-prior

What is the posterior predictive of a normal distribution with normal prior over mean and Gamma prior over precision. Thus, what is the distribution of x given:
\begin{equation}
x \sim \mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \lambda^{-1})\\
st.\\
\mu\sim \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_0, \lambda_0^{-1}) \;\;\; and \;\;\; \lambda\sim \mathcal{G}(\lambda; \alpha_0, \beta_0)
\end{equation}

Note: $\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$

I have found the posterior predictive of $x$ when $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_0, \kappa\lambda)$ and $\lambda\sim \mathcal{G}(\lambda; \alpha_0, \beta_0)$. Where $\kappa$ is a positive parameter and lambda is as defined. This is the posterior predictive of the Gamma Normal Conjugate Prior. ([https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf))

I have also found the posterior predictive when there is just a normal prior to the mean, or just a gamma prior to the precision. ([http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/BDA3.pdf](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/BDA3.pdf))

However, when Integrating the posterior predictive of the above I reach the following dead end:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
%
x&\sim \iint\mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \lambda^{-1})\mathcal{N}(\mu; \mu_0, \lambda_0^{-1})\mathcal{G}
(\lambda; \alpha_0, \beta_0) \; d\mu d\lambda\\
&=\int \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_0, \lambda^{-1}+\lambda_0^{-1}) \mathcal{G}
(\lambda; \alpha_0, \beta_0) \; d\lambda\\
%
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Or my alternative dead end:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
%
x &\sim \iint\mathcal{N}(x; \mu, \lambda^{-1})\mathcal{N}(\mu; \mu_0, \lambda_0^{-1})\mathcal{G}
(\lambda; \alpha_0, \beta_0) \; d\mu d\lambda\\
&= \int T_{2\alpha_0}(x; \mu, \frac{\beta_0}{\alpha_0})\mathcal{N}(\mu; \mu_0, \lambda_0^{-1}) \; d\mu
%
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $T$ is a generalized student-t distribution. *Going via the second dead-end would be ideal for my related work..*

Comment: 1. You don't have a gamma prior on the variance there, but on its inverse ($\lambda$ is the *precision* rather than the variance). Your prior on the variance would be inverse gamma. 2. Minor suggestion: it might help reduce potential confusion a little if your notation didn't conflate the random variable and the argument to the density  3. You seem to be flipping between $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_0^{-1}$ in the integrals and similar issues crop up in a few other places. Can you please double check and correct any dropped inverses on any of the $\lambda$-terms?

Comment: Hey sorry about the confusion. I should have double checked my formulas. Everything should be in terms of precision now. Thank you for your patience.

Also, I have since found that since the T-distribution is not part of the exponential family, dead end number 2 may actually be a dead end...